# Unable to clone - Git Looks for an incorrect certificate path

Tags: git, gitlab-ci-runner

I am into the 5th day of this issue without any luck. I have already gone through the posts in SO, the error already reported are slightly different in nature in that, there they are referring to an incorrect curl ca certificate which git is looking for whereas in my case it is an incorrect ca certificate.

```
C:\Users\Dell2312\Desktop>git clone 
https://sampleurl.githost.io/grp/MyProject.git
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://sampleurl.githost.io/grp/MyProject.git/': 
error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

I do not understand in first place why git should check for a non existing certificate and complaint me about that? What am I supposed to do?

PS: Kindly do not guide me through the links of other SO posts, I have literally gone line by line of each of those posts. None of them suggests the root cause for this and none of the solutions provided work for me.

**UPDATE - Details of my git configuration**

As can be seen, the path which git looks for is 'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt' and the actual certificate path as seen below is C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt

Copying the certificate also did not help

```
C:\Users\Dell2312\Desktop>git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

C:\Users\Dell2312\Desktop>git config --global --list
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: http.sslcainfo is set twice with two different values?

Comment: I don't know how! The second one is where the file actually resides and while cloning, git is looking in the first path..Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: I would start with `git config --global --edit` and remove the double entry for `http.sslcainfo`

Comment: I did it, confirmed by listing again and going to the config file..no luck :-(

Comment: Does it change something if you use \ instead of `/` for the folder delimiters?

Comment: I am not specifying folder path in commands

Answer (score -1):

You are using the HTTPS protocol to clone a git repository, so it is not a surprise that git checks the certificate validity. You have the possibility to use custom certification authorities (CA) and apparently there is a problem with your installation/configuration regarding the location of the CA.

Your configuration can be listed with:

```
git config --list
git config --global --list
```

Maybe you have some `sslCA*` variables set?

If you trust sampleurl.githost.io, you can try if skipping the SSL verification works for you:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://sampleurl.githost.io/grp/MyProject.git
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I understand git checks the certificate validity, since it is HTTPS. As you rightly said, there is discrepancy between actual path of ca and the path which git is looking for - I have posted an edit to my question. I just installed scm git using the default settings and I do not understand why git then looks for the certificate in a different path. I do not have any sslCA variables set. Also, I do not want to skip SSL verification as it is not a recommended approach and I also have to work with numerous other projects using git.

Comment: You are right, disabling SSL verification is bad, I just wanted to confirm that the problem lies in CA verification.

Comment: I presume with the above update - it is evident there is problem with CA path, correct? Also this is what I get copying the certificate from the actual path to the path where git is looking for , `C:\Users\Dell2312\Desktop>git clone https://sampleurl.githost.io/grp/MyProject.git
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://sampleurl.githost.io/grp/MyProject.git
/': error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protoc
ol`  Please let me know if you understand what causes these issues?